# Is there an efficient easy way to test Drupal code while developing it?

Tags: testing

While writing code making sure, for example, I'm access the correct array property I keep refreshing the browser.(Or, that I didn't make a semantic mistake like that last sentence but in code) Is there a very simple and quick why to set up tests to do this instead? Simple test module seems like a huge deal and overkill. I love using Grunt watch while working with node.js. Is there an equivalent in Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

As you're comfortable with Grunt, I've got a Gruntfile that I wrote that I use as a stub for most projects. You can find it here [github.com/Chapabu/grunt-drupal-standards/](https://github.com/Chapabu/grunt-drupal-standards/). Just clone it to your project root and follow the installation instructions.

There are Drupal specific tasks there for doing to following:

- PHP linting of any custom code
- JS linting
- CSS linting
- Automatic clearing of theme registry when new templates are found
- PHP_CodeSniffer tasks to ensure your code mets the [Drupal Coding Standards](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards)

I need to make a few updates (i.e. remove Casper stuff, remove Compass tasks as I now use Libsass etc) but the tasks that are there should be enough to get you started.

There are also Grunt tasks for running [PHPUnit tests](https://github.com/SaschaGalley/grunt-phpunit) or [PHP Mess Detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-phpmd) (to name a couple of helpful suites) so it's pretty easy to add tasks to watches.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already familiar with using Grunt, there's nothing stopping you from using it with Drupal.  Grunt installs the same way on Drupal as with any other site.

Just a a couple of the many useful node-modules you could make use of are:

[grunt-contrig-jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint)
(Can be configured to alert you to potential JS errors as soon as you edit the JS)

[grunt-phplint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-phplint)
(Can alert you to potential PHP errors whenever you edit PHP files)

Livereload - Can be set up to automatically update the page content without refreshing (For CSS and image modifications)